# how to make a side-by-side span into below with each other

Tags: html, css

So good day to all. I would like to ask for some help on how make the span to be below with each other.

```css
div{
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid red;
padding:10px;
height:400px;
}
span{
display:table-cell;
border:1px solid blue;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
</div>
```

As you guys see in the snippet they are side by side.

So how can I make it that each span is below with each other.

If you guys have alternative solution wherein they are below with each other while still vertically and horizontally align, I would gladly try it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `display:table-cell;` to `display:block;` and add padding like follow:

```css
div{
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid red;
padding:10px;
height:400px;
}
span{
display:block;
padding: 100px;
border:1px solid blue;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It somehow solve the issue. I just tweak it a little to apply it in my website..

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
div{
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid red;
padding:10px;
height:400px;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    padding: 50px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
</div>
```

**Trying Adding**

```
span {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    padding: 50px;
}
```